# complex sql multiple table query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need all records from the `URA` table, joined on `dobavljac` for name of the `dobavljac` and all records from `DOSTAVNICA` table based on `dostavnica.ura_id WHERE EXIST ura_id Join on gradilista` for the name of `gradilista`.

Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT

        ura.id,
        ura.id_dobavljac,
        ura.broj_racuna,

        dobavljaci.id_dobavljac,
        dobavljaci.naziv as dnaziv,
        dobavljaci.oib,
        dobavljaci.adresa,

        dostavnica.ura_id,
        dostavnica.id_dostavnica,
        dostavnica.id_gradilista,

        gradilista.id,
        gradilista.naziv

    FROM ura

    INNER JOIN ura ON ura.id = dostavnica.ura_id

    LEFT JOIN ura ON ura.id_dobavljac = dobavljaci.id_dobavljac

    LEFT JOIN dostavnica ON dostavnica.id_gradilista = gradilista.id 
    ";
```

Table schema:

[image: table shema]

and this is what I expect:

[image: final table]

Comment: what is the database you are using ? @Ivan

Comment: please add a tag for dbms you are using.

Comment: mysql - XAMPP v3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :  A brief table structure would have helped. But based on the col names you have in the query I have posted my answer.

```
SELECT

        ura.id,
        ura.id_dobavljac,
        ura.broj_racuna,

        dobavljaci.id_dobavljac,
        dobavljaci.naziv as dnaziv,
        dobavljaci.oib,
        dobavljaci.adresa,

        dostavnica.ura_id,
        dostavnica.id_dostavnica,
        dostavnica.id_gradilista,

        gradilista.id,
        gradilista.naziv

    FROM ura
    INNER JOIN dobavljac ON ura.id_dobavljac = dobavljaci.id_dobavljac
    INNER JOIN dostavnica ON ura.id = dostavnica.ura_id
    WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 from gradilista WHERE dostavnica.id_gradilista = gradilista.id)
```

Comment: final is in php so I check errors: if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
   } an got error: Not unique table/alias: 'ura'. SQL is ok when I have only two tables. URA and DOBAVLJACI

Comment: try now @IvanRadeljak

Comment: Unknown column 'gradilista.id' in 'field list' - that column is in table GRADILISTA as id and primary key

Comment: Need only records from URA and DOSTAVNICA. DOBRAVLJACI and GRADILISTA are two table just for take the name.